# Paraguay Visa Exemption for Canadian visiting Iguazu

Tags: canadian-citizens, paraguay

Paraguay officially requires a visa for Canadian citizens. This is spelled out in the official Canadian site about travel. It says [here](http://Visas%20Tourist%20visa:%20required):

> Visas
>
> Tourist visa: required

However, numerous unofficial online publications say that one can cross into Paraguay without having a visa when entering at Iguazu.

**Is there a visa exemption for Canadian citizens entering Paraguay at Iguazu?**

If so:

- Is there an official policy?
- How long is the exemption valid for?
- Must one exit from the same border entered from?
- Does it matter which border Paraguay is entered from? (Brazil or Argentina)
- Are there unofficial rules applicable to this?

Answer (score 5):

From several travelers I've met and spoken to (including when I was in Iguazu)...

If you're busing over the border to Cuidad de Este, the bus driver wouldn't even stop at the border. You can get dropped off in the city, and picked up again a couple of hours later when the bus comes back. It's a sort of 'we trust you' approach, it seems? Very odd.

However, travellers who wanted to go further (Asuncion), needed a visa.  Go figure.

Sources: https://www.marksmayo.com/2010/07/24/hypothetically-how-to-break-into-paraguay-and-getting-a-blood-test-in-spanish/

https://www.brendansadventures.com/how-not-to-get-into-paraguay/

Comment: Alternatively if you arrive at Silvio Pettirossi International Airport, you can get a visa on arrival.

Comment: The bus stops at the border. Twice actually. It asks everyone to get off for *exit* immigration and then on *entry* immigration getting off is optional. Did this last week.

Comment: @Itai not when I went :/  We exited Argentina, 'zoomed' through Brazil, and when the driver asked if anyone was going further than CdE, didn't bother stopping at immigration in Paraguay. Maybe that's just for Argentina to Paraguay ones :/

Comment: Possibly, I did Brazil to Paraguay and then the next day Paraguay to Argentina... about 10 days ago now... so the direction could matter.